# Fake horizontal scroll bootstrap cards

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I'm building a website and would like to do something like this: https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/NWYxBKO, but instead of images make bootstrap cards.

This bootstrap card:

```
<div class="card w-50">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried many options but couldn't get this to keep the original bootstrap cards shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add .square class alongside your cards div element. It triggers the gsap function.

So, add a bunch of these elements instead of the

```
<div class="card square bg-primary text-white my-3 mx-2">
     <div class="card-body">
         <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
         <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/milan-lakhani/pen/WNawwgZ